# Как менять textview фрагмента в зависимости от case меню?

Tags: android, textview, switch, android-navigation-drawer

Есть боковое меню Expandable Navigation Drawer. Чтобы по нажатию на элемент что-то происходило я использовал `switch/case.`

```
case 1:
                    switch (childPosition) {
                        case 0:

                            break;
                        case 1:

                            break;
                        case 2:

                            break;
                        case 3:

                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
```

Где `case 1` - это открыт элемент меню, а `case 0; case 1; case 2; case 3` - открыт подэлемент меню.

Есть фрагмент с разметкой, в которой находится `textview`.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selected_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/frag1_text">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

В этот `textview` должен выниматься текст из string в зависимости от нажатого подэлемента (`case`). Поскольку фрагмент у меня не один, то сначала в case я вызываю его.

```
    case 1:
                        switch (childPosition) {
                            case 0:

                                fTrans.replace(R.id.frgmCont, frag1);

                                break;                          
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
```

В классе фрагмента прописываю:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, null);

    mSelectedItemView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.selected_item);
    mSelectedItemView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.selected_item),
            null, new MyHtmlTagHandler()));

    return v;
}
}
```

Теперь при вызове фрагмента в `case 0` - вызывается его разметка с `TextView`, который берет текст из `string.selected_item`, вызвав этот же фрагмент в `case 1` (второго подэлемента) - произойдет тоже самое. На экране будет тот же текст из `string.selected_item`. Но мне нужно, чтобы из этого же TextView брался текст из `string.txt_1` например. Не создавать же для каждого `case` фрагмент. Но и прописать строчкой в case:

```
mSelectedItemView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.selected_item);
    mSelectedItemView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.selected_item),
            null, new MyHtmlTagHandler()));
```

меняя в каждом case адрес ресурса: `R.string.selected_item` на `R.string.txt_0` для `case 1` и `R.string.txt_1` для `case 2` и т.д. не получится. Тогда как сделать, чтобы решить мою задачу. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете передать данные о том, какую строку надо вывести в сам фрагмент

```
    frag1 = new YourFragment();// создаете фрагмент
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    int stringId = 0;
    switch (childPosition) {
        case 0:
            stringId = R.string.txt_1
            break;
        case 1:
            stringId = R.string.txt_2;
            break;
        case 2:
            stringId = R.string.txt_3;
            break;
        case 3:
            stringId = R.string.txt_4;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    args.putInt("stringId", stringId);
    frag1.setArguments(args);
    fTrans.replace(R.id.frgmCont, frag1);
```

И теперь в самом фрагменте:

```
mSelectedItemView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.selected_item);

mSelectedItemView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(getArguments().getInt("stringId")), null, new MyHtmlTagHandler()));
```

Comment: В case 0 у меня должен быть другой фрагмент, а в 1,2,3 frag1. Но даже если про это забыть, то все равно выдает ошибку при запуске приложения - NullPointer.

Comment: @Алексей, значит вы что-то делаете не правильно. Как только вы покажете стактрейс ошибки, так и сразу я скажу, что именно не правильно. По тому коду, что вы предоставили, мой ответ работать будет.

Comment: проблема решена, спасибо