# Как сохранить размер TextView для других фрагментов?

Tags: android, textview

У меня есть пара фрагментов с текстом. Мне нужна кнопка, а получается что две, с помощью которых можно регулировать `Size TextView`.

```
case R.id.button3:
                        MyTextView.setTextSize(20.0f);
                        break;
```

Как сохранить полученное значение (размер текста), чтобы передать его другому фрагменту. Т.е., если пользователь выбрал такой размер текста, чтобы он перейдя на второй фрагмент снова не менял размер, а сразу выставился выбранный размер первого фрагмента?

Comment: Так же само, как в этом вашем вопросе http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/548961/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-textview-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-case-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E только передавайте не id строки, а размер текста

Answer (score 1):

Сохраните настройки размера в SharedPreferences, а потом прочитайте их из второго фрагмента.